# Compare Wordpress shortcode with $_GET in loop and return on te right position

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, get, shortcode

I use shortcodes in my Wordpress page. With a query string I compare some data to the shortcodes. The querystring looks like this: ?results&answer1=1&answer2=1

Wordpress example usage:

[answer question=1 image=1]
Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet
[answer question=2 image=1]

The result is however:

```
Image Image
Lorem Ipsum Doler Sit Amet
```

What I would like to accomplish:

```
Image
Lorem Ipsum Dolder Sit Amet
Image
```

The code I've written:

```
function survey_shortcode($atts)
{

    $return = null;
    // Check if ?results is set in the URL
    if (isset($_GET['results'])) {

        // Loop all url values
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {

            // Check if value url matches 'answer'
            if (trim($key, ' 0123456789') == 'answer') {
                //Split data by "-" to array
                $data = explode("-", $value);

                //Check if question matches and has variables set (image)
                if ($atts['question'] == $data[0] && $atts['image'] == true) {

                    // If value is true or 1 -> show image true, otherwise show image false
                    if ($data[0] == "true" || $data[0] == "1") {
                        $return .= '<img src="/wp-content/themes/markteffectief/images/navbg.png">';
                    } else if ($data[0] == "false" || $data[0] != "0") {
                        $return .= '<img src="/wp-content/themes/markteffectief/images/navbg.png">';
                    }
                // If no image variable is set -> view data
                } else if ($atts['question'] == $data[0]) {
                    $return = $data[0];
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        $return = null;
    }

    return $return;
}

add_shortcode('answer', 'survey_shortcode');
```

I guess it runs a loop through the $_GET and adds everything to $return .= some-image. 
I want it have it returned immediately, so it shows up on the right position (the position where I set the shortcode). How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try the_content hook, where you would parse content and replace shortcode with yours

```
function my_the_content_filter($content) {
 return str_replace("[shortcode]", "your code", $content);
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
```